# m2m_changed not trigger for custom "through" model

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I have a custom `through` intermediary model for ManyToManyField between `Wishlist` and `Product`:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created', )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Wishlist(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='WishlistProduct', null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created', )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class WishlistProduct(models.Model):
    wishlist = models.ForeignKey(Wishlist)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created', )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s in %s' % (self.product.name, self.wishlist.name)
```

And a `m2m_changed` signal:

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Wishlist.products.through, dispatch_uid='m2m_changed_wishlist_products')
def m2m_changed_wishlist_products(sender, instance, action, *args, **kwargs):
    print(sender)
    print(action)
```

The `m2m_changed` signal is not working, why?

But the `post_save` signal for WishlistProduct will be trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You signal is probably being garbage collected. Pass in *weak=False* to *connect* method.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#listening-to-signals